Adafruit MCP2111 board gpioget: error reading GPIO values: No such file or directory
When plugging in a Adafruit MCP2111 board, and running
gpioget 1 0 
gpioget: error reading GPIO values: No such file or directory

the board is detected:
lsusb
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 04d8:00dd Microchip Technology, Inc. MCP2221(a) UART/I2C Bridge

dmesg identifies the board:
[  126.875885] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  126.875889] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[  126.894934] mcp2221 0003:04D8:00DD.0003: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microchip Technology Inc. MCP2221 USB-I2C/UART Combo] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input2

drivers are loading fine:
lsmod | grep 2221
hid_mcp2221            20480  0
industrialio          126976  1 hid_mcp2221
hid                   180224  3 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_mcp2221

the device node /dev/gpiochip1 shows up when I plug in the MCP2111 board:
ls /dev/gp*
/dev/gpiochip0  /dev/gpiochip1

the gpiochip0 is part of my laptop, the gpiochip1 shows up after MCP2221 board is plugged in.
gpiodetect sees the MCP2221 and it does have 4 GPIO lines.
gpiodetect
gpiochip0 [gpio_ich] (61 lines)
gpiochip1 [mcp2221_gpio] (4 lines)

gpioinfo 1
gpiochip1 - 4 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high

Here's the issue:
gpioget 1 0
gpioget: error reading GPIO values: No such file or directory

except the gpioinfo above shows that device 1 line 0 is input.
Am I missing something? All this was done from root although the error message isn't complaining about permissions anyway.
The laptop's built-in gpiochip0 has some inputs as shown on
gpioinfo 0
gpiochip0 - 61 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused  output  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high

so trying to read the laptop's chip I/O pin 1 (so it should be readable)
gpioget 0 1
1

works fine.
Could this be a MCP2111 driver problem?
What else can I do to narrow this down?

Can you run strace gpioget 1 0 and share the output? This should help identify what path is used when returning the error.
